# Why does acceptsFirstResponder get called twice when I switch views?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have three views in a window. One of them is a view I have customized so that it draws something, and this view is the `firstResponder` of this window.

When I build and run this app or switch back to this view, the `acceptsFirstResponder` method gets called twice, which is confusing me. Why does that method get called an additional time? Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you care? What are you doing in the `acceptsFirstResponder` method?

Comment: No any reason, I just want to know the detail inside. If I add something into this method, something will be run two times. That may be terrible.

Comment: The only thing you should do in that method is return `YES` or `NO`. You might need to override `becomeFirstResponder` however, does that get called more than once?

Comment: Both becomeFirstResponder and resignFirstResponder get called only once. So I don't understand the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a callback used by the AppKit to understand how your view works. You should not base any decisions on how frequently or infrequently a method like this is called.

If you're truly curious why it's being called more than once, you may be able to guess by putting a breakpoint inside the method. When the breakpoint is hit, look at the backtrace to see the names of the AppKit methods higher up the stack.

For example, imagine code in AppKit like this admittedly contrived example:

```
- (void)_syncFirstResponderStatusOfView:(NSView *)view withWindow:(NSWindow *)window {
    if ((view == [window firstResponder]) && ![view acceptsFirstResponder]) {
         // Perhaps the view changed its mind about accepting first responder
        [window _makeFirstResponder:nil];
    } else if ((view != [window firstResponder]) && [view acceptsFirstResponder]) {
        [window _makeFirstResponder:view];
    }
}
```

That code calls [view acceptsFirstResponder] twice. You could also imagine the value being checked in one function, and based on the result the view is passed to another function, that also checks again, perhaps because it can be entered through multiple code paths and that was the most straight forward was to write it.